# Make class expecting a template template parameter of single template parameter accept a template template parameter of variadic template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, template-templates

I'm trying to write something that is similar to `std::bind`, but for template types instead of objects.  Effectively, I would like to bind one template parameter to a template type.  (In a sort of similar way, in `std::bind` we bind one (or more) real parameters to a function-ish object.)

What I want is best illustrated by the following C++ code:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

/* This struct should be in some header-only utility library */
template <template <typename...> typename Template, typename T>
struct template_bind {
    template <typename... Args>
    using template_type = Template<T, Args...>;
};


/* This class should be in a separate header file */
// If we change the following line to add '...' then it works
// template <template <typename...> typename Template>
template <template <typename> typename Template>
class my_complicated_class {
public:
    /* stuff */
private:
    Template<float> data_;
};

/* This probably would be in a third file that includes both headers */
int main()
{
    using t1 = template_bind<std::tuple, int>;
    using t2 = template_bind<t1::template_type, double>;
    my_complicated_class<t2::template_type> stuff_with_tuple; // Compile error

    using p1 = template_bind<std::pair, int>;
    my_complicated_class<p1::template_type> stuff_with_pair; // Compile error
}
```

Interestingly, the code compiles on GCC and MSVC with C++17, but does not compile on Clang (with whatever C++ standard) or GCC/MSVC with C++14.  The error (on those compilers that won't compile it) is that `my_complicated_class` requires a template template parameter that takes in a **single** template parameter, but `template_type` is a **variadic** template.

Changing `my_complicated_class` to accept a variadic template template parameter fixes the problem on all compilers.  However, it would feel weird to change `my_complicated_class` to accept a variadic template template parameter, because `my_complicated_class` probably shouldn't know anything about the template template parameter that is used.  (Otherwise, an argument could be made that all template template parameters should be written as variadic templates, e.g. `template <template <typename...> typename Template>`, but that does not seem to be way template template parameters are usually written.)

Which compiler(s) is/are non-conformant, and how can I make the code compile on a C++14 compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang does not support C++17 template template argument/parameter matching.

The relevant paragraph:

- [C++14/[temp.arg.template]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.arg.template#3)

> A template-argument matches a template template-parameter (call it P) when each of the template parameters in the template-parameter-list of the template-argument's corresponding class template or alias template (call it A) matches the corresponding template parameter in the template-parameter-list of P. [...]

- [C++17/[temp.arg.template]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg.template#3)

> A template-argument matches a template template-parameter P when P is at least as specialized as the template-argument A. [...]

This is this last sentence that makes your code well-formed in C++17. When P is `template<class> class` and A is `template<class...> class`, P is more specialized than A.

Comment: Is there no way to make something similar work on a C++14 compiler?

Comment: @Bernard There are so many work around. What is acceptable dependens on what your are ready to change in your code. Why don't you define `my_complicated_class` as you say in your code comment:`template<template<class...>class> class my_complicated_class`.